# Python XML compare Tree's

Tags: python, xml, tree, compare, lxml

I want to compare the XML tree structure of 2 XML files:

File 1:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?><DATA>
   <Time>2016-02-12T00:00:00.211Z</Time>
   <Item>
      <ID>123456789</ID>
      <VAR1>897654564dDJUHFKHJHEU</VAR1>
   </Item>
   <Check>OK</Check>
</DATA>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?><DATA>
   <Time>2016-02-13T00:05:00.531Z</Time>
   <Item>
      <ID>888555444</ID>
      <VAR1>ABCD_MKLS8866dee6</VAR1>
   </Item>
   <Check>FAILED</Check>
</DATA>
```

My Code:

```
from lxml import etree

tree1 = etree.parse('file1.xml')
tree2 = etree.parse('file2.xml')

print(tree1.getroot())
print(tree2.getroot())

print set(tree1.getroot()) == set(tree2.getroot())
```

When I compare them the result == false. The result should be == true...
How can I Compare only the tree structure and not with the values?

Answer (score 2):

Why they aren't equivalent is a good question. I'll have to look it up myself. However, you can compare list equivalency if you flatten the trees using `.iter()` -- the following example is verbose for sake of clarity:

```
from lxml import etree

xml_1 = '<tag1><tag2></tag2></tag1>'
xml_2 = '<tag1><tag2></tag2></tag1>'

xml_1_parsed = etree.fromstring(xml_1)
xml_2_parsed = etree.fromstring(xml_2)

xml_1_flattened = [i.tag for i in xml_1_parsed.iter()]
xml_2_flattened = [i.tag for i in xml_2_parsed.iter()]

print xml_1_flattened == xml_2_flattened
```